# Using year-week column as x-axis for bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I try to plot a `bar plot` with `matplotlib` to show the change of an aggregated number on a weekly basis over time (my dataset has roughly 1000 weeks). Normally, when I plot such time-series, I have daily data and I convert the dates with `pd.to_datetime()`. But in the weekly case, don't know how to specify the format in order to get an accurate `x-axis` labels with the years and not also with the weeks which overlay on each other.

This would be a simple data set example:

```
    YearWeek    Output
0   2022-01     7.3
1   2022-02     5.3
2   2022-03     7.2
3   2022-04     4.8
4   2022-05     5.8
5   2022-06     9.2
6   2022-07     5.3
7   2022-08     5.3
8   2022-09     7.5
9   2022-10     9.2
10  2022-11     5.4
11  2022-12     4.8
```

[image]

In the case of more weeks, the `x-axis` is not readable and the labels lie on each other. I try to only get yearly labels.

This would be the plot for the real data set I am using:
[image]

For reproducibility:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'YearWeek':['2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03', '2022-04', '2022-05', '2022-06', '2022-07', '2022-08', '2022-09', '2022-10', '2022-11', '2022-12'],
    'Output':[7.3, 5.3, 7.2, 4.8, 5.8, 9.2, 5.3, 5.3, 7.5, 9.2, 5.4, 4.8]}) 

plt.bar(df1['YearWeek'], df1['Output'])
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit1: Added `plt.xticks(df1['YearWeek'],df1['YearWeek'].str[:4])` to show only the year instead of year-week on x-axis.

Edit2: x-axis will show each year only once.

You can rotate x-axis ticks by 90 degrees or 45 degrees using `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'YearWeek':['2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04', '2021-05', '2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-08', '2021-09', '2021-10', '2021-11', '2021-12', '2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03', '2022-04', '2022-05', '2022-06', '2022-07', '2022-08', '2022-09', '2022-10', '2022-11', '2022-12'],
    'Output':[6.3, 5.3, 7.2, 4.8, 8.8, 9.2, 5.3, 5.3, 4.5, 9.2, 5.4, 4.8, 7.3, 5.3, 8.2, 4.8, 5.8, 9.2, 5.3,2.3, 7.5, 9.2, 5.4, 9.8]}) 

df1['Year'] = df1['YearWeek'].str[:4]

plt.bar(df1['YearWeek'], df1['Output'])
# plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xticks(df1['YearWeek'],df1['Year'])
plt.xticks(np.arange(6, len(df1), 12))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Output of Edit2:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In my real dataset, I have roughly 1000 weeks and the bars are only a line. Do you know how to convert the YearWeek column to datetime so it only displays the year?

Comment: @fjurt, add this line `plt.xticks(df1['YearWeek'],df1['YearWeek'].str[:4])` before `plt.show()`

Comment: @fjurt, I just saw your read data chart. It looks like there's too much data cramped in it. If its past few years of data, would it not be better to show data by year than by week? Have a bar for each year or month to make it more readable?

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions. In my case, it would be nice to show weekly figures.

Comment: @fjurt, got it. I might have found a solution to show years only once. Have a look.

Comment: great, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You're welcome @fjurt ... helps me learn in the process too

Answer (score 1):

one solution could be to rotate them :

```
...
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. In my real dataset, I have roughly 1000 weeks and the bars are only a line. Do you know how to convert the YearWeek column to datetime?

Comment: @fjurt why would you wanna do that? what's the origina problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to show the weekly aggregated numbers of news articles over several years.

Comment: @fjurt isn't your data on weekly bases already? or you want to show them for each year now?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I added the plot of my real data in the question. The only thing I struggle with is the x-axis label (I want to only display the years and not year-weeks)

Comment: @fjurt hmm.. still, I think that would be not enough ...

Comment: hmm okey, thanks for your effort:)